# if $\ T_a(S_1) \cap T_a(S_2) = \{0\}$ then there exists a neigberhood $U$ of $a$ such that $\ U \cap S_1 \cap S_2 = \{a\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry

I would like some help on the following question.
Let $S_1,S_2$ be differential manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Let $a \in S_1 \cap S_2 $.
Prove that if $\ T_a(S_1) \cap T_a(S_2) = \{0\}$ then there exists a neigberhood $U$ of $a$ such that $\ U \cap S_1 \cap S_2 = \{a\}$. Where $\ T_a(S) +a \  $ is a tangent space for the differential manifold $S$ in point $a$.

I've managed to prove it for the case when $S_1,S_2$ are both from dimenstion $k-1$ by showing there exists a neigberhood $U$ of $a$ such that $\ U \cap S_1 \cap S_2$ is a $k-2$ differential manifold. If we assume (towards contradiction) that for a neigberhood $U$ of $a$ such that $\ U \cap S_1 \cap S_2 \neq \{a\}$, then there must be exists $b\neq a,b \in S_1 \cap S_2 $ and then $ \{b-a\} \in\ T_a(S_1) \cap T_a(S_2) \to \ T_a(S_1\cap S_2) = \ T_a(S_1) \cap T_a(S_2) \neq \{0\} $. We got a contradiction, therefore there exists a neigberhood $U$ of $a$ such that $\ U \cap S_1 \cap S_2 = \{a\}$.
However, I couldn't generalize it for the case where $S_1,S_2$ don't have the same dimension.

Thanks in advance.